# Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/38

Tags: android

I added the permission on the manifest.xml

But I still having the same error:

> Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider

Help me please.

My java class

```
     package com.example.maymaa.mytest;
      +import..

   public class Image extends AppCompatActivity {
   private static final int PICK_IMAGE =100;
   Uri imageUri;
   ImageView imageview1;
   Button button;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);
   imageview1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
   button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btphoto);
    assert button != null;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         openGallery();

        }}
    );}
 private void openGallery()

{


   Intent gallery= new Intent    
  (Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);


    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}

  @Override
  protected  void onActivityResult
          (int requestcode,int resultcode,Inten  data)       
{

  super.onActivityResult(requestcode,resultcode,data);

      if(resultcode == RESULT_OK && requestcode==PICK_IMAGE){
          imageUri =data.getData();
          imageview1.setImageURI(imageUri);
  }

   }

  }
```

My activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="361dp"
    android:layout_height="255dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageview1"
    android:layout_weight="0.14" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Choisir"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="btnclick"
    android:id="@+id/btphoto"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

My code is not working
 Thank you

Comment: HTML will never throw error.

Comment: Sorry i made a fault :/  at android

Comment: Your using marshmallow?

Comment: Then you need to request to user for permission programatically. refer this : http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: post the code of your activity.

Comment: my activity contain just a button and an image view

Comment: at the reality i m new membre here!! i have no idea how to add a long code.. when i click add comment and paste the activity s code ,it can t be published !!

Comment: Below your question your are having there things writen, share/edit/flag. Just click on edit > Paste your activity code and Save the edit. :).

Answer (score 0):

Add external read/write permission in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: i did .. but the problem is not solved ,i have the same error                                                                               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.example.maymaa.mytest"

>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>


    <application
       
    </application>
   
</manifest>

Comment: Otherwise I m damm sure u r missing some permission

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Put this code in onCreate right after setContentView and put the remaining code of onCreate in else part:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        int hasWritePermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int hasReadPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (hasWritePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        } else {
            preferencesUtility.setString("storage", "true");
        }

        if (hasReadPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        } else {
            preferencesUtility.setString("storage", "true");
        }

        if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
            requestPermissions(permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]), REQUEST_CODE_SOME_FEATURES_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }
```

out side onCreate write :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_SOME_FEATURES_PERMISSIONS: {
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    System.out.println("Permissions --> " + "Permission Granted: " + permissions[i]);
                } else if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    System.out.println("Permissions --> " + "Permission Denied: " + permissions[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
        default: {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue ,
Have provided permissions as below in manifext.xml

```
**<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>**
```

Thanks
Krish